# Need to find the Vab of this circuit!

Tags: calculus

V = IR

I = 4ma = 0.004A
R = 2 ohms

what is V?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point at which you are evaluating the potential is between the two resistors so you have to be careful about combining the resistors.

First you need to figure out how much current is running through each wire. You can do this by realising that the volage drop crossing the top loop will be,

$$ I_T 15\Omega = V_0,$$

and crossing the bottom loop will be,

$$ I_B 25\Omega = V_0.$$

Dividing these gives us,

$$ I_T = \frac{25}{15}I_B. $$

Since the total current is 4 amps we conclude that,

$$ 4A = I_T+I_B = I_B (\frac{25}{15}+1) = \frac{8}{3} I_B$$

So that $I_B = 1.5 A$ and $I_T=2.5A$.

Now we see that,

$$ V_{ab} = -1.5*10V + 2.5*10 V = 10V$$

Comment: I follow all up until the end, I think you meant to type 10V!  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for catching that. I sometimes get a little sloppy with the arithmetic when answering questions here.